# TraCI file has a priblem

Tags: python, sumo

I've written a little code in python for getting connected to `sumo` as follows:

```
    import traci
    traci.start(sumoCmd)
    step = 0
    while step < 200:
       traci.simulationStep()
       traci.vehicle.add('x', typeID='DEFAULT_VEHTYPE')
       step += 1
    traci.close()
```

1 - The GUI's answer is:

- Loading is done.
- Simulation started with time: 0.00**
  I want to know why nothing is shown in GUI?

2 - Is there any order in TraCi to say `sumo` do something? (describing lane, edge, route, vehicle, etc?)
p.s. Sorry for my mistake in the title

Comment: Did you press the green "Play" button in the GUI?

Comment: Yes of course. I found what the point is. I increased the departure time because my route was not long enough to get the car in the simulation.